# To prevent multiple login with same user Id

Tags: vb.net

I had implement session to store the user id, but after that i realized that only work for single browser not for different browser. I think the session is store in the browser. Do you guys got any idea implement this?

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this is that I log the date/time the user logs *in* and *out* of the program/website, for example:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| username | lastLoggedIn      | lastLoggedOut
---------------------------------------------------
| Joe      | 06/05/2015, 17:12 | 06/06/2015, 17:16
---------------------------------------------------
| Bob      | 04/05/2015, 19:16 | 04/05/2015, 20:21
```

My code then compares the `lastLoggedIn` entry with the `lastLoggedOut` entry; if the `lastLoggedOut` entry is *earlier* than the `lastLoggedIn` entry, then the user is still logged in and we can prevent them logging in again.

To verify this, we need to compare the two entries, firstly splitting them into separate `Date` and `Time` variables and then working on the values given.

As the author of the question has pointed out:

> what if the user simply closes their browser without logging out
>   first?

This situation is slightly trickier to handle, but nonetheless doable. I'm unsure for VB.NET, but for C# you are able to *catch* a browser closing event by using `onbeforeunload`.
If you're using HTTP Keep Alive ([*it can be enabled in IIS, see here*](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d7e13ea5-4350-497e-ba34-b25c0e9efd68.mspx?mfr=true)), simply scan the concurrent server connections for the IP; if it is not found then update the user's `lastLoggedOut` field.

> what if the web server crashes when users are logged in?

Though hopefully you've programmed your web application so that won't happen, a crash or power outage *could* happen at *any time*. This does mean that users will still be listed as *logged in* in the database.
To fix this, simply add a check when the web-app starts up to check for users still listed as logged in; you can then 'log them out' by replacing the entry with a valid one.

For completion, you might also want to dump the members who were 'repaired' by the system into a file so that if any of them have further issues you have an audit trail.

Comment: Actually i have implemented something similar. How about when the user close the browser and session time out? how to store the last logged out?

Comment: @wksl That situation's slightly tricky, are you using HTTP Keep Alive? If so, check the concurrent connections for the user's IP address, if their IP address is not found then log them out this way. You could also do this without HTTP Keep Alive, but I have a feeling it'd require WMI and since WMI eats system resources like there's no tomorrow, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I not using HTTP Keep Alive. This problem was bother me 2 weeks, i was keep trying to find the solution.

Comment: @wksl I'd appreciate it if you could review the edit and give feedback.

Comment: Can you show me how to code the HTTP keep alive?

Comment: @wksl I linked it already in my answer. It's a setting on IIS.